# traces are not being shown in zipkin, when sender type is kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, zipkin

I want to send my spring boot log traces using Kafka to Zipkin server

I started my Kafka and Zipkin servers and I started a Kafka consumer which is listening to the topic Zipkin and I am able to see my logs here but when I open my Zipkin dashboard I can't find any traces

**Spring boot version** :- 2.1.7.RELEASE
**Spring Cloud version** :- Greenwich.SR2

### depedendency Management

```
    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>Greenwich.SR2</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
```

### dependencies

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

### My application.properties file

```
        spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1 

        spring.application.name=dummy

        spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://localhost:9411

        spring.zipkin.sender.type=kafka
```

### SpringBootApplication Main file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### My Controller function

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String sayHello() {
    log.info("hey im a log");
    return "hello";
}
```

when i make **spring.zipkin.sender.type=web** the traces are being shown in Zipkin dashboard 
Is there anything I'm missing here.

Comment: set type=kafka instead of type:kafka? You can try to run your app with -Ddebug=true to get more info

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Im sorry I made a typo while writing the question, In my application it is  spring.zipkin.sender.type=kafka only but it still ain't showing logs

Comment: The traces are going into Kafka as I'm running a consumer which is consuming the topic zipkin and whenever I hit any endpoint the log is being generated and it is being displayed in the consumer cmd line,but it is not going to Zipkin

Comment: Thanks for your help @MarcinGrzejszczak, I wish I specified my command line terminals too, and then maybe you would have instantly figured out what my problem was. Anyway, I really appreciate the help and hope to see a new video on youtube on Microservices tracing with Spring Cloud and Zipkin in spring cloud Greenwich.SR2 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I finally realized whats the mistake that I have done when I was starting my zipkin server with this command

```
 java -jar zipkin-server-2.16.2-exec.jar
```

but I was not specifying my Zipkin server where my Kafka is running so when I did

```
 set KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:9092
 java -jar zipkin-server-2.16.2-exec.jar
```

it worked